# How to connect to AWS EC2 instance wwwroot folder?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I have a AWS EC2 instance and I want to access the wwwroot folder in that instance using my C# windows application. Is it possible to do so? I'm able to connect to the instance using the following code, but have no clue how to access the

**C:/inetpub/wwwroot** folder.

```
IAmazonEC2 clients = new AmazonEC2Client(_awsAccessKey, _awsSecretAccessKey, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.APSoutheast2);
```

*Note: I don't want to use amazon S3 bucket.*

Comment: If the instance was just another computer on your work network, how would you access the `wwwroot` folder? You'd probably do the same thing with the EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

The Amazon EC2 SDK can be used to *control* Amazon EC2 instances (eg launch an instance, stop an instance, attach an EBS volume), but **it cannot be used to do any *on* the instance**.

Once an Amazon EC2 Windows instance is running, it is just like any other Windows computer. You can connect to it just like you would any other computer (eg RDP, disk shares, web server) but it has additional layers of security you might need to satisfy (eg Security Groups).